# jQuery manage many toggles

Tags: javascript, jquery, slidetoggle

I need to use `slideToggle()` for too many divs to show and hide them.

This is my code, it doesn't work correctly:

```
$(".account-update").hide();
$(".account-update-pwd").hide();

$(".slide-toggle").click(function() {
    $(".account-update").slideToggle();
    $(".account").slideToggle();
});
$(".slide-toggle-pwd").click(function() {
    $(".account-update-pwd").slideToggle();
    $(".account-update").slideToggle();
});
```

**HTML**:

```
<a href="#" class="slide-toggle">Update Account</a>
<a href="#" class="slide-toggle-pwd">Change Password</a>
```

Comment: Can you please add some more HTML and JS as well?

Comment: This works fine for me, try this:
https://plnkr.co/edit/oc0kdwVuAg26TT4fZaie?p=preview

Comment: Offir Pe'er ,  it doesn't work correctly:

Comment: @Flex_able What do you mean by "correctly"? Write what is your expected result and what actual happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated your `code` with a nice generic solution below.

```js
$(".account-update").hide();
$(".account-update-pwd").hide();

$("a.slide-toggle").click(function() {
  var targetDiv = $($(this).attr('data-selector'));
  var otherDivs = $("div.slide-toggle").not(targetDiv);
  
  otherDivs.each(function(){
    if($(this).is(':visible')) {
      $(this).slideToggle();
    }
  });
  
  targetDiv.slideToggle(function(){
    if($("div.slide-toggle:visible").length === 0) {
      $(targetDiv.attr('data-default')).slideToggle();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
}

.account {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

.account-update {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}

.account-update-pwd {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slide-toggle account">Account Div</div>
<p><a href="#" class="slide-toggle" data-selector=".account-update">Update Account</a></p>
<div class="slide-toggle account-update" data-default=".account">Account Update Div</div>
<p><a href="#" class="slide-toggle" data-selector=".account-update-pwd">Change Password</a></p>
<div class="slide-toggle account-update-pwd" data-default=".account">Account Password Update Div</div>
```

Comment: The "account"  is default div ." Update account"  and  "change password"  works up of "account div.

Comment: @Flex_able Do you want to toggle this "account" div? You can check my code and advise if you need any changes.

Comment: "account" is the default div where I put the data of account. When show Account then "update account and change password" hide. WHen I show update account then account and change pwd hide;    It works between 3   DIV .

Comment: Sorry for my bad  english. there are 2 buttons. and 3div . the red div is default not an "option button". when I open the page the default div account show the data account. Wheb I click update then update account shoes and account and change password hide. When I clik change password account and update account hide.

Comment: ok, but I need also the account update is closed then account shows, and when change pwd is closed account is show

Comment: it works also horizontally?  DIV are show vertically.

Comment: @Flex_able Yes, it will

Comment: @Flex_able Great :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you can create unique class for toggle buttons, then you can do something like this:

```js
$('body').on('click', 'a,button', function(e){
  if ( $(e.target).attr('class') === 'btn-toggle' ) {
    $(this).css({
      color: 'red'
    })
  }
});
```

```html
    
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <a href="#" class="btn-toggle">aaaa</a>
 <a href="#" class="btn">aaaa</a>
 <a href="#" class="btn">aaaa</a>
```

Short and simple :)

Comment: My example work like a charm. Just customize it to your liking.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this.

```
$(".toggle-trigger").on("click", function() {

    var trigger = $(this);
    var target = trigger.attr("data-entity");

    if (!trigger.hasClass("active")) {

        $(".toggle-trigger").removeClass("active");
        trigger.addClass("active");
    } else {

        $(".toggle-trigger").removeClass("active");
        trigger.removeClass("active");
    }

    $(".toggle-target[data-entity='"+ target +"']").toggleClass("hide");
});
```

How to use

```
<a class="button toggle-trigger" data-entity="container-one">Container One Link</a>
<a class="button toggle-trigger" data-entity="container-two">Container Two Link</a>

<div class="container toggle-target" data-entity="container-one">Container One</div>
<div class="container toggle-target" data-entity="container-two">Container Two</div>
```

What it does is, when you clicked `toggle-trigger` which is the links to trigger the container. It will get an attribute called `data-entity` which is the unique parameter to find the container's `data-entity` to toggle things up.